# Is "Communication design" is the same as "Design Communication"?

Tags: website-design

I want to know if the meaning of communication design is the same as design communication?

Comment: First is design used for better communicating what you want to get across (think infographics, readable pie charts) while second is design that have it's own meaning (think silver in Apple or rounded cars that are sold as "for women")

Comment: Depends entirely on who is using the terms and *context*.  Is "Family friendly" the same as "Friendly family"?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a *good* query here, *and* how best to frame it. We strongly prefer questions which *do **not*** primarily generate opinion-based answers - this seems likely to get close votes on that basis. It's also, as currently formatted, more fit for purpose over at [english.se] - perhaps should be migrated there in fact. Please read [ask] and revise your question a bit - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication design is what one does when he thinks how to communicate, what to communicate and with whom to communicate. The communication itself is under planning, it has not yet happened.

Some goals of communication design

- catch the attention of people to be able to input something
- input to people ideas that they wouldn't get without external impulses
- show to people ways to act due the feeded ideas

Marketing efforts need communication designers. As useful they are for ambitious politicians. History shows that clever communication can create a new truth which looks out so real and important that people lose their individuality and behave together like an ox who rushes where its head is turned to.

Design communication happens when different persons co-operate in a design project and exchange data, ideas and opinions. The communication actually happens. Actually no design team can be effective without well working communication. The team communicates between its members, the client, their organizational management and their service providers.

Answer (score 0):

In 1973, I got a degree from University of Illinois Circle campus in *Communications Design*, what it was called back then.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE**: *Please* read **[tour]** to get a sense of our community. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to answer it. We're typically looking for longer answers that provide some explanation and context; we prefer that answerers *don't* just give a *one-line* answer; they explain **why** their answer is right, ideally with citations or *clear examples*. Answers that don't include explanations or details may end up being removed; remember, this should be just as much for *future* searchers as for *this* asker.